# User profile pages do not come with a pixelated title in the default theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I didn't notice earlier because of my modifications, but the user profile page does not sport a pixelated title.

Answer (score 2):

The fix should be in the next deployment. please verify.

Comment: Verified. [ ](http://o/~)